# How to quickly remove stains made of semen from clothes

Tags: cleaning, clothing, sex

Maybe some of you have had the bad experience to get semen stains on your clothes after having a sexual intercourse with your partner in a public place (for example at a party, in the office, in your car ...). In this case you both are usually hidden somewhere in a separate room and after that you have to walk through a place full of many people and it is uncomfortable to have this stains on your clothes. In this case you need to remove it from your clothes quickly, but without having a washing machine and much time.

Using some water, wet napkins, and after that some dry napkins usually have a good result depending on the type of clothes. In some cases, especially when the clothes are black, this method is not good enough.

So the question is: Is there a better method for quickly removing stains made of semen from clothes?

Comment: I don't know if this is even a serious question, but if it is you'll want to describe why/how your (admittedly working) solution didn't work in some scenario, and what that scenario is. Note that the current answer assumes you have time to actually wash the material, which I suspect doesn't apply.

Comment: I can't understand what exactly you can't understand. Could you explain it more clear. I vave explained the problem, I mentioned what I have already tried and why this is not a satisfactory solution. If you can tell me where I am wrong I will edit it to be more clear.

Comment: The comments that made me doubt this is a sincere question? Yeah, if you gotta ask...

Comment: @Shog9 Since it is mentioned as stain, I answered in that way. If it is to remove semen, then the word stain shouldn't be used. We can not edit without knowing the intention of the OP. Vladiz, pls edit clearly

Comment: Not blaming you for the question being unclear, @Joachin - just using your answer to demonstrate how unclear it is.

Comment: @Joachin Joseph Why semen and stain cannot be used at the same time? It is a stain made of semen. If it is only stain then it won't be correct because there are stains made of different things, for example : blood, ketchup, oil ...

Comment: @vladiz Usually stain means a mark, refers dry mark on fabric. But your intention was to clean the mark of fresh incident. This created the confusion.

Comment: Whoa. This question is +10/-10. Some people have strong opinions about this one.

Comment: @Shokhet guess people don't think such stains should exist in the first place...

Comment: @ShadowWizard NO STAINS SHOULD EVER EXIST!!1!1!!

Answer (score 19):

Of course its best to avoid this altogether. So having a [hanky](https://www.google.de/search?site=&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1778&bih=959&q=stofftaschentuch&oq=stofftaschentuch&gs_l=img.3..0l3j0i24l7.4593.7329.0.7888.16.12.0.4.4.0.141.961.10j2.12.0.msedr...0...1ac.1.60.img..0.16.969.YL_YhH3Ddek) ready (that is outside of a container) and close to your hand (e.G. in your [jackett](https://www.google.de/search?site=&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1778&bih=959&q=Jackett+Herren&oq=Jackett+Herren&gs_l=img.3..0.1243.4025.0.4199.14.8.0.6.6.0.95.585.8.8.0.msedr...0...1ac.1.60.img..0.14.597.jattLoTQ-Xs)/coat pocket) and apply directly after/during ejaculation will reduce the amount of situations where leftovers are on clothes. If you happen to have this kind of sex regularly this should be a permanent preparation.

To clean: **First remove the semen** as quickly as possible by placing your finger next to it (not on it) and roll it up while moving over the semen. Use each finger only once or clean it after use with a towel. Speed is important. Most fabric will not soak up the liquid instantly so you can reduce the intense of the spot if you remove it quicker. Semen is kinda sticky and so is your finger. This works best on jeans or similar fabric that is kinda water repelling. If available, use tampons for this task, they work even better then fingers.

The goal here is to **lift** the semen **from** the **fabric**, be careful not to rub it in more then absolutely necessary.

Then spit on your hand (or use water if available) and press the cleaning liquid through the fabric (from the inside) so that the ejaculate is diluted and replaced by spit / water. The goal here is to **replace** the highly visible white **semen with** a less visible kinda **clear liquid**.

Then **wait** as long as possible. Semen changes color to a semi-transparent yellow after some minutes and thus becomes less visible, also some parts dry. If possible press fabric that is not visible (socks) on the wet spot to dry it quicker. DO NOT USE PAPER TOWELS! They are likely to leave small white particles on your clothes that shine like stars on black fabric.

If nothing helped, create a distraction. If you wear a shining red flower in your jackets front pocket nobody will care about your pants. Of course that only works so long, so be sure to properly clean yourself soon or go grab your spare pants from the car.

Comment: OR you might draw a flower with the semen, and make it look like it's part of the fabric... :-)

Comment: @LaurentS. bazinga!

Answer (score 13):

**Level 1:** Soak in cold water for an hour and rub it. It will loosen the stain on the fabric. Then agitate with detergent soap /liquid on that area, rinse with cold water and dry in shadow.

**Level 2:** If the above step fails, Rub the stained area with dishwasher soap and wash thoroughly with cold water. These are little more powerful than launders.

**Level 3:** If you still see the mark on the fabric, add a pinch of baking soda on the stained region, rub for 20-30 secs and rinse thoroughly with cold water.

**Level 4:** There are available enzyme cleaners at market even in food stores. This will help you out.

**TIPS:**

- Seminal fluid is rich in fructose & protein(albumin). It is like other organic stain. So rinsing in hot water will coagulate the semen stain firm. It can literally make the stain permanent.
- Seltzer water is good option while rubbing. Pretreating with soda also helps.
- Adding Hydrogen Peroxide is an optional while washing. If a washing machine is used, just add one spoon. It is good bleaching agent.(Do not add too much on dark clothes)
- Acetic acid(vinegar), citric acid(lemon) are conventional methods but I do not recommend on colored clothes.
- The faster you take action, the more likely you are to achieve a result.

Comment: How does that apply to the question? OP asked for a  quick solution that can be applied in minutes not hours. While what you write is correct for the situation where one has time, but for the situation the OP described its kinda inapplicable.